# finding within array of object angular 6/typescript/javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am having below code in my HTML template of my angular 6 application.

```
<div *ngIf ="conversation.participants[conversation.updatedBy.toLowerCase()].firstName">somedata </div>
```

basically I am trying to search within object of participants array by updatedBy value anad see its matching object has firstName property not null or not but it gives me error that firstName is not defined.

I also tried placing question mark after ] brackets  like below but did not yield any result.

```
conversation.participants[conversation.updatedBy.toLowerCase()]?.firstName
```

Below is json object

```
"participants": [{
        "dateJoin": 1520409578,
        "dateLeft": 0,
        "firstName": "edh",
        "internalId": 165,
        "invitedBy": "edh",
        "lastName": "edh",
        "userId": "edh"
    }, {
        "dateJoin": 1520409578,
        "dateLeft": 0,
        "firstName": "",
        "internalId": 166,
        "invitedBy": "edh",
        "lastName": "",
        "userId": "ATB"
    }],
    "dataInAB": "ATB",
    "subject": "test ",
    "unreadMessageCount": 0,
    "updateDate": 1520585258,
    "updatedBy": "atb"
}
```

Please let me know if anything you know about this.

Thanks

Comment: Provide more code so I can help

Comment: If you are getting *firstName not defined", then there's definitely something wrong with `participants[conversation.updatedBy.toLowerCase()]`

Comment: I added json object, if this is wrong, please suggest me having other way to make this happen

Comment: conversation.updatedBy.toLowerCase() - this should be numeric value(index number) - you are access the object from array - check it once

Comment: Since participants has array of objects, you have to pass index value (number) to access it's values participants[atb] is undefined because its not available

Comment: I am migrating angularjs application to angular6 application, this  might be wrong, proivded logic what could be alternative, may be I can write some function in .ts file and could see but if you have any idea on this.  I want to check if conversation updatedBy values matches within array of object of participants, return the value of firstName ? any logic on this.

Comment: conversation.updatedBy.toLowerCase() is not a index. That's why you are getting undefined. Can you let know what conversation.updatedBy.toLowerCase() returns?
Or you can just create a function in ts to get the first name and call that function in HTML.

Comment: I want to return true if conversation.updatedBy value matches within array of object of pariticpants if matches want to see firstName is null or not.  updated by returns atb

Comment: the logic I would like to have is if updatedBy value matches within array of object of participants [ it checkes for userID of participants]. if matches return the firstName property of that object. may be someone can help me with .ts file function logic

Comment: any help here pls

Comment: What is the output you are expecting here? Also why are you doing `conversation.participants`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare a variable in your component.ts file which will store the boolean result that you are using in `*ngIf`. And also update the value when the `conversation` variable changes.

For example, in **component.ts**

```
let firstNameExists = false;

getConversationData(){
  this.conversation = ....
  this.firstNameExists  = this.conversation.participants.find(m=>m.userId.toLowerCase()==this.conversation.updatedBy).firstName? true: false;
}
```

and then in your **component.html**

```
<div *ngIf ="firstNameExists">somedata </div>
```

Note: the expression is being used in ts because it's a very bad practice to use expressions in angular bindings.

Comment: If this was your desired solution, then please mark as answer

Answer (score 0):

```
this.conversation.participants.find(x => x.userId.toLowerCase() === this.conversation.updatedBy).firstName;
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-paqbmr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)